# Why am I having trouble selecting a default radio button on a web page?

Tags: asp.net, html, radio-button

It seems this ought to be dead simple, but I'm stuck.  I've written some asp.net code that outputs a pair of radio buttons:

```
<p>
<label for='chkYapper'>Yapper</label>
<input type='radio' name='yapper' id='chkYapper' value='yapper' checked='<%=gblYapperChecked %>' />
<br />
<label for='chkNonYapper'>non-Yapper</label>
<input type='radio' name='Yapper' id='chkNonYapper' value='nonYapper' checked='<%=gblNonYapperChecked %>' />
```

```
        if (registrationUser.isYapper == 1)
        {
            gblYapperChecked = "checked";
            gblNonYapperChecked = "";
        }
        else
        {
            gblYapperChecked = "";
            gblNonYapperChecked = "checked";
        }
```

As expected, I get two radio buttons, "Yapper" and "Non-Yapper".  However, even when I step thru my code and see that gblYapperChecked is "checked" and gblNonYapperChecked is "", Non-Yapper is always selected by default in the web browser.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**Here is the HTML code as it actually appears in the browser.  "Yapper" should be selected, but "Non-Yapper" appears selected instead.

```
<p>
<label for='chkYapper'>Yapper</label>
<input type='radio' name='yapper' id='chkYapper' value='yapper' checked='checked' />
<br />
<label for='chkNonYapper'>non-Yapper</label>
<input type='radio' name='yapper' id='chkNonYapper' value='nonYapper' checked='' />
```

Comment: Set the name to be the same, it is case-sensitive

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the name; however, it does not do anything to fix the problem.

Comment: @Adam - Names are case sensitive, but it shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: Try putting this code in OnPreRender event handler - right now I assume it's in OnLoad or OnClick, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the HTML "checked" attribute is generally determined by being present or not present. See `http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-checked` for the spec.

In particular what this means is that if you want it to be checked you cna have `checked`, `checked=true`, `checked=checked` and so on. So what you want is to not have the checked attribute at all if you don't want the checkbox selected.

I would advise structure such as:

```
<input type='radio' name='Yapper' id='chkNonYapper' value='nonYapper' <%=registrationUser.isYapper?"":"checked='checked'" %> />
```

This should eliminate your checked attribute entirely dependant on your isYapper boolean.

Answer (score 3):

The "checked" attribute is weird, it has no value. If a radio button is checked, include the "checked" attribute by itself in the tag. If unchecked, don't do anything. See here:

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_RADIO.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting dblYapperChecked before or after the control is created?  Personally, I'd run the radio buttons on the server side and set the checked value on the control directly, but your method should work if the values are set soon enough (try initializing them to the expected values and see if that makes a difference...)